# Need a return Statement? - new to coding

Tags: java, bluej

The idea is different lots in an auction. I know I need a return statement of type "Lot" however I am not sure what that would be. Here is my code.

```
public Lot getLot(int lotNumber)
{
    int index = 0;
    boolean found = false;

    while(index < lots.size() && !found) {
        Lot selectedLot = lots.get(index);
        if(selectedLot.getNumber() == lotNumber) {
            found = true;

        }
        else {
            index++;

        }

    }

    if(!found) {
        found = false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `selectedLot`?

Comment: And why is `found` important? Just return the lot when you find it, no need to keep on trucking to the end of the array. Or return `null` if the loop manages to terminate.

Answer (score 6):

What you could do is something similar to this, what this will do is if a match is found it will return the selectedLot which was the match, and if no match was found it would return null:

```
public Lot getLot(int lotNumber) {
    int index = 0;

    while(index < lots.size()) {
        Lot selectedLot = lots.get(index);

        if (selectedLot.getNumber() == lotNumber) {
            return selectedLot;
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use following code:

1) returns last Lot with some number

```
  public Lot getLot(int lotNumber)
    {
        int index = 0;
        Lot resultLot = null;
        while(index < lots.size() ) {
            Lot selectedLot = lots.get(index);
            if(selectedLot.getNumber() == lotNumber) {
                resultLot = selectedLot;
            }
            else {
                index++;
            }
        }
        return resultLot;
    }
```

2) or (returns first Lot with some number)

```
public Lot getLot(int lotNumber)
{
    int index = 0;
    while(index < lots.size() ) {
        Lot selectedLot = lots.get(index);
        if(selectedLot.getNumber() == lotNumber) {
            return selectedLot;
        }
        else {
            index++;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

3) or (smaller example)

```
public Lot getLot(int lotNumber)
{
    for(Lot selectedLot: lots) {
       if(selectedLot.getNumber() == lotNumber) {
            return selectedLot;
        } 
    } 
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: Finally one guy that uses a for loop instead of the whiles... +1

Answer (score 1):

```
public Lot getLot(int lotNumber) {
    int index = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    Lot selectedLot = null; //set initial value to null

    while(index < lots.size() && !found) {
      selectedLot = lots.get(index);
      if(selectedLot.getNumber() == lotNumber) {
         found = true;
      }  else {
        index++;
      }

    }
    return selectedLot; //You need to return type Lot 
}
```

when you say `Lot getLot(int lotNumber)` you are basically saying that you are returning an object of type Lot, but you never return it in your code

Comment: by doing that it gives the error "cannot find variable Lot"

Comment: @jjbb93 I apologize you should be returning the variable `selectedLot`, I updated it

Comment: one more thing, your `if(!found) { found = false}` was redundant, it was already set to false no need to set it again